# Paypal Subscription Integration

Tags: javascript, html, css, paypal

Relatively new in trying to create a Paypal subscription service. I am using HTML with PHP and Javascript. I have my development environment ready but I am confused on the second part of the process.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#2-create-a-product

[image: 1]

where do I place that code in Create a product? not sure if I will encase it in PHP or a separate javascript file.

Comment: the code you've shown a pretty picture that is using a program called `curl` to make the request - if you're using PHP, normally you'd use the appropriate PHP function to make the request - but since this is a one time operation, you probably just do the above as shown using `curl`

Comment: You have to write PHP curl script to make this call. If you don't want to refresh the page, use ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

try to go to your terminal and go to the project's path and copy and paste the command on your terminal